# Adding a number to every element

Tags: calculations

I have a table, whose entries are a list of one or more numbers. Now, I need that all numbers in the table are to be incremented by 1. For example, say, I have the table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            1, 2, 4  & 2, 3, 4 & 5, 0, 1 \\ \hline
            1, 2 & 3 & 2, 5, 7 \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want that, the first row- first column entry will be `2, 3, 5`, ... & so on. How can I do that?

**UPDATE**

Many thanks to *@egreg* for this quick solution. Just one thing I need to know: How can I keep some cells as it is. Suppose, my table is like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
            \hline
            1, 2, 4  & None & 5, 0, 1 \\ \hline
            1, 2 & 3 & None \\  \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Can I keep `None`s intact?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here it is! With `collcell` we pass the cell's content to the `\increment` macro for being processed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,collcell,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\increment}{m}
 {
  \pushpen_increment_cell:n { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_cell_seq
\seq_new:N \l_pushpen_cell_incr_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pushpen_increment_cell:n #1
 {
  % split the cell contents into a sequence
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_pushpen_cell_seq { , } { #1 }
  % map the sequence into another incrementing each item
  \seq_set_map:NNn \l_pushpen_cell_incr_seq \l_pushpen_cell_seq { \int_eval:n { ##1 + 1 } }
  % produce the sequence, items are separated by “comma and space”
  \seq_use:Nn \l_pushpen_cell_incr_seq { ,~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\None}{\multicolumn{1}{l}{None}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ *{3}{>{\collectcell\increment}l<{\endcollectcell}} }
\toprule
1, 2, 4  & 2, 3, 4 & 5, 0, 1 \\
\midrule
1, 2 & 3 & 2, 5, 7 \\
\midrule
1, 2 & 3 & \None \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same, but with much clumsier code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,collcell}

\newcounter{liststep}
\newrobustcmd\increment[1]{%
  \setcounter{liststep}{0}%
  \forcsvlist{\addone}{#1}%
}
\newcommand\addone[1]{%
  \ifnum\value{liststep}>0 , \fi
  \number\numexpr#1+1\relax
  \stepcounter{liststep}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| *{3}{>{\collectcell\increment}l<{\endcollectcell}|} }
\hline
1, 2, 4  & 2, 3, 4 & 5, 0, 1 \\ \hline
1, 2 & 3 & 2, 5, 7 \\  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But I'm getting `! Undefined control sequence.
\increment ...eq {\int_eval:n {##1+1}}\seq_use:Nn 
                                                  \l_pushpen_cell_incr_seq {, }
l.18 1, 2, 4  &
                2, 3, 4 & 5, 0, 1 \\ \hline
? `

Comment: This is my `latex -v`: `pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)
kpathsea version 6.1.1    ...`

Comment: @pushpen.paul You need an updated TeX Live 2014, for the slick solution. I'll try adding another one based on less efficient tools.

Comment: Would you mind to solve my next problem? I just saw the table has a few `None` entries. `:-(`

Comment: @pushpen.paul `\newcommand\None{\multicolumn{1}{l}{None}}`